# python scope: nonlocal variable evaluation where function is defined versus where it's called

Tags: python, scope

For the below, I get `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`. But there is an x defined when otherFcn() is called. From this error, I learned that Python looks for a nonlocal variable from where the function is defined, not where the function is called.

```
def otherFcn():
    print('inside of fcn ', x)

def main():
    x = 12
    otherFcn()

main()
```

But why then does this below print "inside secFcn 100"? Shouldn't it print "inside of secFcn 24" if Python looks for what x is at the point where the function is defined and not at the point where the function is called.

```
def main():
    x = 24
    
    def secFcn():
        print('inside secFcn ', x)

    x = 100
    secFcn()
main()
```

Comment: Use `global x` to define variable in global scope.

Comment: Functions inherit their parents' scope (second example). In your first example, the parent scope of `otherFcn` is the root-scope, and not the scope inside the `main` function.

Comment: " I learned that Python looks for a nonlocal variable from where the function is defined, not where the function is called." yes, this is called *lexical scope* as opposed to *dynamic scope*. Lexical scope is used in pretty much all languages you might use today (with the exception of some shell languages like bash!)

Comment: you have changed `x` to 100 before `secFcn()` was called and `x` visible in function `secFcn` because it is in one scope of function `main`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't it print "inside of secFcn 24" if Python looks for what x is at the point where the function is defined and not at the point where the function is called.

It looks for the variable in the *scope* where the function was defined, but it does *not* look for the value the variable had at the *time* the function was defined. It looks up the current value of the variable.

At the time `secFcn` tries to use `x`, `x` evaluates to `100`, not `24`.

Answer (score 1):

> From this error, I learned that Python looks for a nonlocal variable from where the function is defined, not where the function is called.

This is not true. What you’re experiencing is a general programming concept known as “Scope.” In both examples `x` is a local variable with function scope, and in both cases that function is `main()`.

Your error occurs in the first example because you’re trying to access `x` outside of its scope. As far as Python is concerned that variable doesn’t exist within the scope of `otherFcn()`.

The second example allows `secFcn()` to access `x` because of where that function is defined. By defining it in `main()` you’re giving it local scope within `main()` and it can access the other variables with that same scope, or with “higher” scope.

If you had defined `x` in global scope then it would share scope with `otherFcn()` and would be accessible. Similarly it would also be accessible by `secFcn()` because the scope of `x` would be “higher” in the hierarchy than the scope of `secFcn()`.

Implementation details will differ from language to language, and I’m sure someone else on here has a clearer or more technically savvy way of explaining it, but as far as I understand it that’s how it works in Python and there’s also quite a bit more to it, so I recommend googling “variable scope in Python” or similar.

Hope that helps,

—K